# random an array only one time php

Tags: php, arrays, random

I want to random an array only one time. I have use array_rand() function. But it rotates it self many time I need to make it only one time rotates. Here is my code,

```
<?php 
    $sum = array("My name is","My surname is");
    $rand_keys = array_rand($sum);
    $usekey=$sum[$rand_keys];
    echo $usekey;
?>
```

Comment: Do you mean you only want to pull one value, but it's pulling multiple values?

Comment: Not clear Please have us your desired  op by the way array_rand accepts 2 arguments ! http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php

Comment: No I want only one rotation and stop execution.

Comment: I have given two elements in the array

Comment: Do you mean if your refresh your page it has a new value?

Comment: yes,sir I mean this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this,

```
<?php
    $sum = [1,2,3,4,5];
    shuffle($sum);
    while($last_element = array_pop($sum)){
      echo "<br>Last element : $last_element";
    }
?>
```

Check here : https://eval.in/535298

Understand about,

**array-pop** : http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php

**Shuffle an array** : http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php